# VueScan correctly scans my image, but MSPaint doesn't work?

Tags: drivers, scanner

I'm using CanoScan Lide20 and since it doesn't have 64 bit driver for Windows 7, I was told VueScan would make it work.

Unbelievably it works, now since I'm developing a software to use the scanner I need it to scan anywhere. Normally on MSPaint I could select the From Scanner option and have that invoke the scanner, but right now it's greyed out.

If VueScan works, doesn't that mean it already installed the required drivers?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used [VueScan](http://www.hamrick.com) for several years, but it's my understanding that VueScan uses its own drivers and accesses the scanner directly. However, the most recent releases seem to have added an intermediate TWAIN driver, so you should be able to use that with any TWAIN-capable programs.